# How do i get RSpec's shared examples like behavior in Ruby Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby, rspec, testunit, minitest

Is there a plugin/extension similar to shared_examples in RSpec for Test::Unit tests?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using rails (or just active_support), use a [`Concern`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f37ad331089f64ab0386e8ac94b6626b45c38a1e/activesupport/lib/active_support/concern.rb).

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module SharedTests
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do

    # This way, test name can be a string :)
    test 'banana banana banana' do
      assert true
    end

  end
end
```

If you're not using active_support, just use `Module#class_eval`.

This technique builds on [Andy H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725792/andy-h)'s answer, where he points out that:

> Test::Unit tests are just Ruby classes, so you can use [normal techniques] of code reuse

but because it enables the use of [`ActiveSupport::Testing::Declarative#test`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a5ab38c7bb99e135e29f5727e3e75a1e562d8216/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/declarative.rb) it has the advantage of not wearing out your underscore key :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to implement shared tests (similar to RSpec shared examples) using the following code:

```
module SharedTests
  def shared_test_for(test_name, &block)
    @@shared_tests ||= {}
    @@shared_tests[test_name] = block
  end

  def shared_test(test_name, scenario, *args)
    define_method "test_#{test_name}_for_#{scenario}" do
      instance_exec *args, &@@shared_tests[test_name]
    end
  end
end
```

To define and use shared tests in a Test::Unit test:

```
class BookTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  extend SharedTests

  shared_test_for "validate_presence" do |attr_name|
    assert_false Books.new(valid_attrs.merge(attr_name => nil)).valid?
  end

  shared_test "validate_presence", 'foo', :foo
  shared_test "validate_presence", 'bar', :bar
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`Test::Unit` tests are just Ruby classes, so you can use the same methods of code reuse as any other Ruby class.

To write shared examples, you could use a module.

```
module SharedExamplesForAThing
  def test_a_thing_does_something
    ...
  end
end

class ThingTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include SharedExamplesForAThing
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'minitest/unit'
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

#shared tests in proc/lambda/->
basics = -> do
  describe 'other tests' do
    #override variables if necessary
    before do
      @var  = false
      @var3 = true
    end

    it 'should still make sense' do
      @var.must_equal false
      @var2.must_equal true
      @var3.must_equal true
    end
  end
end

describe 'my tests' do

  before do
    @var = true
    @var2 = true
  end

  it "should make sense" do
    @var.must_equal true
    @var2.must_equal true
  end

  #call shared tests here
  basics.call
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this gist I wrote a couple of years ago. It still works great: https://gist.github.com/jodosha/1560208

```
# adapter_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

shared_examples_for 'An Adapter' do
  describe '#read' do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Used like this:

```
# memory_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

describe Memory do
  it_behaves_like 'An Adapter'
end
```